# 4 bytes to decimal - C# From Windev

Tags: c#, windev

I have this 4 bytes : 0x41 0xCC 0xB7 0xCF
and I must to find the number 25.5897503.

With Windev, a sample uses the Transfer() function but I can't find equivalent in C#

Could you help me with some indications ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert byte array to Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979164/efficiently-convert-byte-array-to-decimal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a `Single` precision needed. So use `ToSingle` method in the `BitConverter` class:

```
byte[] array = new byte[] {0x41, 0xCC, 0xB7, 0xCF};
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(array, 0);
```

Beware of Little / Big Endian though. If it doesn't work as expected, try to reverse the array first:

```
byte[] array = new byte[] {0x41, 0xCC, 0xB7, 0xCF};
Array.Reverse(array);
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(array, 0);
```

**EDIT:**

Or, as [Dimitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) suggested, you could also use `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to check the *endianess* of the converter:

```
byte[] array = new byte[] {0x41, 0xCC, 0xB7, 0xCF}; //array written in Big Endian
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) //Reverse the array if it does not match with the BitConverter endianess
    Array.Reverse(array);
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(array, 0);
```

Comment: `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to check the actual endian (and *generalize* your solution): `float value = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? BitConverter.ToSingle(array.Reverse().ToArray(), 0) : BitConverter.ToSingle(array, 0);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my answer with little modification for readability! ;)